# AngularJS Select with ng-options on array of objects

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

My Data looks as below:

```
  {
    "count": 0,
    "QHPIssuerNames": [
        "NOV BCBS",
        "mark issuer",
        "Release 3 issuer",
        "Los angles issuer"
     ],
    "QDPIssuerNames": [
        New One",
        "jan issuer",
        "Manage Issuer",
        "test enrollment",
        "testing issuer p"
    ]
}
```

And I want to add a select to my html loading the data from the array.

```
<select 
    name="issuer" 
    id="issuer"
    ng-init="vm.selectedData = vm.inputData.issuer[0]" 
    class="form-control" 
    ng-model="vm.inputData.issuer"
    ng-options="label group by group for value in vm.inputData.issuer"></select>
```

[image: Here is the screenshot of how my dropdown should look like]

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g43du2h9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution involves transforming the `object of arrays` into and `array of objects`, I tried creating a solution with the original object, but the problem is that I am not able to create multilevel select using the object. It requires the object to be split into individual elements for me to get the desired result, basically I loop through the original array and delete the first entry which is `count:0`, since its not needed in the iteration process, then assign the values to the final array.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
  vm = this;
  vm.inputData = {
    "count": 0,
    "QHPIssuerNames": [
      "NOV BCBS",
      "mark issuer",
      "Release 3 issuer",
      "Los angles issuer"
    ],
    "QDPIssuerNames": [
      "New One",
      "jan issuer",
      "Manage Issuer",
      "test enrollment",
      "testing issuer p"
    ]
  };
  vm.newArray = vm.inputData;
  delete vm.newArray.count;
  vm.finalArray = [];
  for (var k in vm.newArray) {
    for (var j of vm.newArray[k]) {
      vm.finalArray.push({
        key: k,
        value: j
      })
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller='MyController as vm' ng-app="myApp">
  <select name="issuer" id="issuer" class="form-control" ng-init="vm.selectedData = vm.finalArray[0]" ng-model="vm.selectedData" ng-options="x.value group by x.key for x in vm.finalArray"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to add two more strings ("All Health Issuer", "All Dental Issuer"  to the front of the object array as shown in the image

Comment: @dragonfly For that first you should share the complete json you are working with!

Comment: @ Naren Murali -- I'm getting json as response from a http request. But the string ("All Health Issuer", "All Dental Issuer") is not part of the response. I have to add it to the final array